# which is right way to call write()?

Tags: linux, system-calls

ers:
There is a question perplex me. As far as I know, there are two ways to call write() in Linux. Like this: 
Code 1:

```
write(DEV, buf, count);
```

Code 2:

```
int write_total = 0;
while (write_total < count) {
    int len = write(DEV, buf, count);
    write_total += len;
}
```

Is there any distinction if DEV is network or device? 
My leader told me the Code 2 is correct way if DEV is network fd because of its streaming.
Who gives security that writing counts chars to DEV? Kernel or programmer?

Thank you !

Comment: This depends a *lot* on what kind of object the FD is pointing to, but in general you should use the second (after fixing the bugs, handling errors, and usually buffering on `EAGAIN` as well)

Comment: `pipe(7)` is a good read, since it shows most of the interesting behavior, without too much fluff.

Comment: You should *carefully* read [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) (and more generally the documentation of every function you are using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for `write` to actually write *fewer* bytes than you requested so the first option can't be relied upon.

However, the second option is also not viable since, if it wrote ten of the twenty bytes you requested, you would then attempt to write *all* those bytes again.

A better approach would start with something like:

```
int bytes_written = 0;
while (bytes_written < count) {
    int len = write(DEV, &(buf[bytes_written]), count - bytes_written);
    if (len < 0)
        break;
    bytes_written += len;
}
```

This adjusts the data you attempt to write each time based on the amount already written. It also detects errors and stops the operation in that case.

And, needless to say<sup>(a)</sup>, this should probably be refactored into a `write_no_matter_what()` function so that your main code isn't peppered with repeated segments like this.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Yet, for some bizarre reason unknown to me, I'm saying it :-)